# Prevent user from tampering score

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario in which user would do a series of tasks on the web app, and submit the score to my server for storing. How can I prevent the user from tampering the score? The app is in JS (i.e. not Java, Flash etc.)

I understand that I can make the score variable private but that doesn't stop users from using the chrome debugger or whatnot to pause the execution and figure out the code.

I can think of 2 points of attack:

1. Modify the score in runtime memory from the JS code
2. Capture the HTTP request and forge one with fake score

How can I prevent these?

Comment: You can't prevent it entirely. Even if you obfuscate your code, someone will be clever enough to reverse engineer it and manually craft an HTTP request to your server.

Comment: No, if it's a rigid requirement then store the score on the server and have the server do the calculations for the game logic.